# How to typeset keywords in svn-multi

Tags: svn-multi

I am using the svn-multi version 2.4d as version control for my LaTeX projects.  However,
I cannot get the various keywords typeset.  Despite the invocation of `\svnid` and/or `\svnidlong`, things like `\svnrev`, `\svndate` etc contain only random noise.  Is there anything
else than svn checking, svn checkout and svn update that I need to do to make `\svnrev` etc contain correct information?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces this issue. If the input data inside `\svnid{$Id$}` or `\svnidlong ..` is correct the values provided by `\svnrev` etc. should be fine, too. Note that the `autokw` option will not work for newer Standalone versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example how I use `svninfo`. The package `svn-multi` should work in the same way.

In your document(s) there should be something like:

```
\usepackage[...]{svninfo}
[ ... ]

\svnInfo $Id: ch00-preface.tex 80 2012-12-06 08:56:15Z herbert $

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Preface}}
[...]
```

then you can use all that commands which `svninfo` defines. Important is that you activate your files with svn for using the Id line:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Id" <file>.tex
```

Only then the status ID line with status informations is updated by svn when comitting the file into the repository. *Before* comitting the first time, it is okay if you have a line like `\svnInfo $Id: $`.